# How to move app in background on "Press again to exist" in android?

Tags: android

I have an activity in which I have implemented onBackPressed method and in this method I have implemented code for "Press again to exist".what I want when user press agin to exist I don't want app to exist I want to run app in background.
How can I do that please tell me solution.

here is my code:-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Use    

    moveTaskToBack(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `moveTaskToBack(true);`

```
if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

**EDIT**

Try something to this effect. This will exit on successive back press within 500 millis. Change 500 milliseconds to your own taste.

```
long lastPressTime = 0l;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

 if( (currentTime-lastPressTime) < 500l )
 {
    // Double Press
    moveTaskToBack(true);
 }

 else
 {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    lastPressTime = currentTime;
 }
}
```

Comment: I want to use this method when user press double not in once

Answer (score 0):

Try This is a very simple way to achieve this

```
private int i = 0;//this is activity's global variable
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   ++i;
   if(i==1)
      Toast.makeText(this, "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  else
      finish(); 

}
```